# Multiple threads adding to child collection results in StaleObjectStateException

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate

I have a situation where multiple threads load the same entity `Job` and then each thread adds to its child collection `Set<JobError>`. I can understand this exception if the parent itself was updated, but the only 'change' to the parent is the addition to the collection, even then?

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB")
public class Job extends BaseEntity {

private Set<JobError> jobErrors = new HashSet<JobError>();


/**
 * @return the jobErrors
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
public Set<JobError> getJobErrors() {
    return jobErrors;
}

/**
 * @param jobErrors
 *            the jobErrors to set
 */
public void setJobErrors(Set<JobError> jobErrors) {
    this.jobErrors = jobErrors;
}

/**
 * Helper to take care of both sides of the association
 * @param message
 * @param currentProfileId
 */
public void addError(String message, Long currentProfileId,
        String firstName, String lastName) {
    JobError er = new JobError(message, currentProfileId, firstName,
            lastName, this);
    jobErrors.add(er);
}
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB_ERROR")
public class JobError extends BaseEntity {
private Job job;

    public JobError(String description, Long profileId, String firstName,
        String lastName, Job job) {
    this.description = description;
    this.profileId = profileId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.job = job;
}
/**
 * 
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", nullable = false)
public Job getJob() {
    return job;
}

/**
 * @param jobErrors
 *            the jobErrors to set
 */
public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}
}
```

Service Code, this runs in multiple concurrent threads:

```
job = jobDao.findById(er.getJobId(), false);

for (Long profileId : er.getProfileIds()) {
// do stuff
try {
    sendEmail(emailTemplateDto, user);
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    job.addError(re.getLocalizedMessage(), currentProfileId, profile.getPersonalData().getFirstName(), profile.getPersonalData().getLastName());
}
```

Once the service method returns which is annotated as `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` the StaleObjectStateException is thrown:

```
2013-03-28 13:22:52,578 ERROR     org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(324):  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.test.project.domain.Job#2]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1950)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2594)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy162.processSendEmail(Unknown Source)
at com.test.project.service.messaging.EmailRequestMessageListener.onMessage(EmailRequestMessageListener.java:57)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:560)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:498)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:439)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:311)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$2.onMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:287)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1321)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I can think of nothing else except for trying to save `JobError` directly. Currently I first load `Job`, add to the collection of `JobError` and then `merge` Job and hope the cascade.merge will take care of saving the child collection.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of the exception in question, but if not it is going to cause problems down the line: HashSet is not a thread-safe collection, which means that if two threads call addError at the same time then one of the errors might not make it into the set.  You'll either need to add the "synchronized" keyword to the addError method, or else you'll need to replace the HashSet with a thread-safe alternative, e.g. a ConcurrentLinkedQueue or ConcurrentHashMap